# Find files that have an extension larger than a specific number

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I am attempting to create a script that will search through a directory for files whose extension are larger than a specific numerical value. The process I am monitoring creates files with numeric extensions when it runs. My end goal is to delete all files of a certain file name one the extension exceeds 800.

The process runs and creates a file as a result, mainly a log files. When it creates its 800th file the file name would be like "filename.800". The file name can vary but the extension will be anything from 000 - 999. I need to delete "filename.*" for the collection of files that reaches 800 (or other). There are other files of different names but have numeric extensions as well in the same directory. I'm trying to make this part of an automated cleanup process.

I could use some suggestions on how to get started detecting the files exist. My initial attempt below does not seem to heed the 'GTR', 'LSS' options.

```
forfiles /M *.* /C "%comspec% /c IF @EXT GTR 800 (ECHO @PATH)"
```

I don't mind entertaining other methods to address my task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @ext value includes enclosing quotes, so you need to include them in your IF comparison. But adding quotes will throw off the command line parser since the entire command is already enclosed in quotes. Use 0x22 to represent each internal quote.

```
forfiles /M * /C "cmd /c if @ext gtr 0x228000x22 echo @path"
```

However, FORFILES is very slow. It is much faster to use a simple FOR loop. The `~x` modifier expands to the file extension (including the dot).

The following works on the command line.

```
for %f in (*) do @if %~xf gtr .800 echo %f
```

Double the percents if you want to use the command in a batch script.

Comment: Thank you for the extra detail in your solution both using "forfiles" and "for"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the files *precisely* in the 800-999 range, then the easiest and fastest way is this:

```
for %%a in (8 9) do del filename.%%a??
```

Previous method could even be adjusted for other different ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

::method1

FOR %%f IN (*.8* *.9*) DO IF %%~xf gtr .800 IF %%~xf leq .999 ECHO %%f

:: method2

ECHO ======= method 2 ============
FOR %%f IN (*.8* *.9*) DO (
 ECHO %%~xf|FINDSTR /r ".[89][0-9][0-9]$" >NUL 
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO %%f
)
```

The first method may suit, but it also detects filenames such as `xxx.8004` `xxx.8a9`.
The second method is slower, but I believe will reliably detect only filenames that end ".[8 or 9][2 digits]"

The filenames are only `ECHO`ed to the console. Replace the `ECHO` with `DEL` to delete the files - after rigorous testing...